# How to apply behavior set by jquery to multiple elements with same class but different values for controlling variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html layout where there is a left well of content, and in the right well, an image or some other block of content. At some point as the user scrolls and that block of content in the right well gets to the top of the screen, it's position gets changed to fixed. As it hits the bottom of it's parent element, it's position changes to absolute and scrolls off the screen with its parent element.

I have this set up currently here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdhancock88/6hLJF/, where my javascript/jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var offset = $('.rightWellContainer').offset(); /*gets top and left position of the div containing the image*/


$(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() +20; /*sets variable for the top of the window scroll, plus 20 (for the items's padding) */
    var specialHeight = $('.special .leftWell').height(); /*gets the height of the row containing the element */
    var imageHeight = $('.imageContainer img').height(); /*gets the height of the element */
    var mark = (offset.top +specialHeight - imageHeight); /*sets the mark at which the element should top scrolling and switch to position absolute by adding the element's start position (offset.top), to the row's height (specialHeight), minus the height of the object (right4Height)*/

    /* when the top of the object is less than the top of the window's scroll AND the object hasn't reached the bottom of the row (mark > scrollTop), add fixed class to freeze object in scroll */

    if (offset.top < scrollTop && mark > scrollTop) {
        $('.rightWellContainer').addClass('fixed');
        $('.rightWellContainer').css('top', 20);
    } 

    /*remove the fixed class when the object should scroll with it's row */

    else {
        $('.rightWellContainer').removeClass('fixed');
        $('.rightWellContainer').css('top', 0);
    } 

    /*if the top of the object hits the point (mark) where it's at the end of it's row as it scrolls off the window, add position absolute so the object scrolls up with the bottom of its row */

    if (scrollTop >= mark) {
        console.log("You hit the mark");
        $('.rightWellContainer').addClass('bottom');
        $('.rightWellContainer').css('top', specialHeight - imageHeight);
    }


    /*if the object has the absolute positioning on it already and falls back past the top of the window (scrollTop), place it back fixed within it's row by removing the class "bottom"*/

    if (scrollTop < mark && $('.rightWellContainer').hasClass('bottom')) {
        $('.rightWellContainer').removeClass('bottom');
    }
});
```

});

What I'm wondering is, if I wanted to add a second piece of right content in a separate parent div with the same behavior, how would I set up my current javascript/jquery to apply that behavior to each piece of right content independent of the others?

Comment: why you get the offset at first ? `var offset = $('.rightWellContainer').offset();`. this dont change by user navigation!!

Comment: It's to be able to use the offset.top() value, which is checked against the scrollTop and in the mark calculation.

Comment: in your example i cant see left and right content evry content are under each other and also i cant see image!!! , please re check it!

Comment: In the jsFiddle, the left content is the latin text, the right content/image is represented by the red box. Looks fine when I click on the jsFiddle link

Comment: sorry i dont see any red box in your example!!

Comment: Are you clicking on  http://jsfiddle.net/jdhancock88/6hLJF/? If so, in the result pane (bottom right), you should see some latin text. Scrolling down, to the right of the text, there is a red box. You might need to expand the result pane or scroll to the right a little.